# I want to calculate the cv error of the smooth.spline fitting function in R, however, it shows the error below:

Tags: r, regression

My function should return a `data.frame` object giving K-fold error estimates for: polynomial regression, cubic splines, and smoothing splines, with the degrees of freedom ranging from `df.min` to `df.max`. However, my smoothing splines is not working like the other two models,  it shows up this error: Error in data$y[-train] - preds2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator. 
`I wonder why poly and cubic spline is working but not smoothing spline?` Does anyone knows how to fix this?

```
# This part is working fine
smoothCV_1 <- function(x, y, K = 10, df.min = 1, df.max = 10) {
  train=sample (c(TRUE ,FALSE), nrow(spline.data),rep=TRUE)
  cv.error2 <- rep(0,10)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    if(i >= 3) {
      spline.fit <- lm(y ~ bs(x, i), data = spline.data, subset = train)
      preds1 <- predict(spline.fit, data)[-train]
      cv.error[i]= mean((data$y[-train] - preds1)^2)

      glm.fit = glm(y ~ poly(x, i), data=spline.data, subset = train)
      preds2 <- predict(glm.fit, data)[-train]
      cv.error2[i]= mean((data$y[-train] - preds2)^2)
    } else {
      cv.error[i]= NA

      glm.fit = glm(y ~ poly(x, i), data=spline.data, subset = train)
      preds2 <- predict(glm.fit, data)[-train]
      cv.error2[i]= mean((data$y[-train] - preds2)^2)
    }
  }
  cv.df <- data.frame(degree = 1:10, cv.error = cv.error, cv.error2 = cv.error2)
  return(cv.df)
}
smoothCV_1(x,y,10,1,10)
```

```
# This part is problematic
smoothCV_3 <- function(x, y, K = 10, df.min = 1, df.max = 10) {
  train=sample (c(TRUE ,FALSE), nrow(spline.data),rep=TRUE)
  cv.error2 <- rep(0,10)
  for (i in 1:10) {
    if(i >= 1) {
      fit2 <- with(smooth.spline(x, y, df=i), data=spline.data, subset = train)
      preds2 <- predict(fit2, data)[-train]
#This part shows error:
#Error in data$y[-train] - preds2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
      cv.error2[i]= mean((data$y[-train] - preds2)^2)
      print(cv.error[i])
    } else {
      cv.error2[i]= NA
    }
  }
  cv.df <- data.frame(degree = 1:10, cv.error2 = cv.error2)
  return(cv.df)
}
smoothCV_3(x,y,10,1,10)
```

Answer (score 1):

This line output a 2-column data frame in a list format:

```
preds2 <- predict(fit2, data)[-train]
```

Suppose we have reproduced your code here:

```
df_ <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4), y = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
train=sample(c(TRUE ,FALSE), nrow(df_), rep=TRUE)
fit2 <- with(smooth.spline(x, y, df=i), data=df_, subset = train)
```

When I run this code: `preds2 <- predict(fit2, data)[-train]`, first, the output of the `predict()` will not be changed, since `[-train]` is a column selection, if you want to select rows do this `[-train,]`.

Secondly the output is

```
$y
   x y
1  0 0
2  0 0
3  0 0
4  0 0
5  0 0
6  0 0
7  0 0
8  0 0
9  0 0
10 0 0
11 0 0
12 0 0
```

So you basically just get a list of data frame.

One way to fix the problem:

```
preds2 <- predict(fit2, df_)$y$y[-train]
```

Comment: Something like this:
$y
                x            y
1    2.3486700928  3.178258953
2    2.3318405015  2.619875178
3    2.3150107305  3.463599675
4    2.2981805324  1.931639310
5    2.2813495967  1.984557054
6    2.2645173597  3.421559253
7    2.2476831946  2.082970562
8    2.2308464745  2.355394136
9    2.2140065169  2.449184001
10   2.1971624167  2.089018910
11   2.1803132130  0.248161151
12   2.1634579282  1.984883214
13   2.1465955176  1.279863211

Comment: @SherylHsiung Would you mind verifying that the shape `preds2 `? Is that a two-column data frame, which is not right. I think that is your input data right?

Comment: Yes, it 's a  two-column data frame. Is that the problem?

Comment: @SherylHsiung I have the same issue when I reproduce your code, I modified it, and it works now, see the code.

Comment: Great, thank you so much! I think it's working! May I ask what's the difference with one $y and two $y$y? Sorry, I'm quite new to R.